# How to become a Google VSA (Vendor Security Assessment) assessor?

Tags: security

I know the Google has Google Vendor Security Assessment (VSA) Program (https://partner-security.withgoogle.com/docs/security_review_process.html). For pass this program, it required a **Google-empanelled third-party assessor** to conduct a security assessment.

> Assessments will be conducted by a Google-empanelled third-party assessor. The cost of the assessment typically varies between $10,000 -$75,000 (or more) depending on the size and complexity of the application; smaller applications may see costs at a lower threshold of $4,500. This fee may be required whether or not your app passes the assessment and will be payable by the developer. We expect that fees will include a remediation assessment if needed.

Ref: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#zippy=%2Chow-will-the-security-assessment-work

As I know now, Bishop Fox and Leviathan are the assessors.

Any one know how to become an assessor of this program?